# Copying multiple rows and pasting to another worksheet based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rows based on user input on what date is to be copied. And then this will be pasted to another worksheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
Dim a, b
Dim pastews As Worksheet, copyws As Worksheet, theRow As Long

Set copyws = Sheets("Tracking")
Set pastews = Sheets("Tracking_new")
    
a = Application.InputBox("Enter the date to be copied.", Type:=1)

If TypeName(a) = "String" Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo badID:
    theRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, copyws.Columns(1), 0)
On Error GoTo 0



b = Application.InputBox("Enter the row number to be inserted into.", Type:=1)
If TypeName(b) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
copyws.Rows(theRow).Copy
pastews.Rows(Val(b)).Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Exit Sub
badID:
MsgBox "invalid ID"

End Sub
```

This only copies the very first row but I need to have all the rows corresponding to the user input. How can I change my code?

Im expecting to see more than 1 rows to be pasted.

Comment: The Match function only returns the first instance of a match found.  If you want them all then either use a filter, or use a loop with a match that doesn't search the whole column but starts in the cell after the previous match.

Comment: Do the source and destination have the same number of columns?

Comment: Yeah they have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Insert/Copy Rows Filtered By an Entered Date Using `AutoFilter`

- Initially, columns `A:G` in the destination worksheet were populated with numbers from `1` to `12`.
- The code was first run with `07/07/2023` and `2` and after that with `07/06/2023` and `8`.
  Note how columns `F` and `G` in the destination worksheet were not affected.

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyByDate()
    
    ' Reference the workbook and worksheets.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Sheets("Tracking")
    Dim pws As Worksheet: Set pws = wb.Sheets("Tracking_New")
        
    ' Copy Worksheet
        
    Dim InputDate: InputDate = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Enter the date to be copied.", Type:=1)
    If VarType(InputDate) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Canceled on date input.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim DateId As Date, DateErrorNumber As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
        DateId = CDate(InputDate)
        DateErrorNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If DateErrorNumber <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date """ & InputDate & """ entered.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the copy table range.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = cws.UsedRange
    ' or e.g. Set crg = cws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim crCount As Long: crCount = crg.Rows.Count - 1
    If crCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data in the Copy worksheet.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the copy data range.
    Dim cdrg As Range: Set cdrg = crg.Resize(crCount).Offset(1)
    
    crg.AutoFilter 1, Array(DateId), xlFilterValues
    
    Dim cvrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set cvrg = cdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    cws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If cvrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No rows with date """ & DateId & """ found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Paste Worksheet
    
    Dim prCount As Long:
    prCount = Intersect(cvrg, cvrg.Cells(1).EntireColumn).Cells.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = cvrg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim PasteRow: PasteRow = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Enter the row number to be inserted into.", Type:=1)
    
    If VarType(PasteRow) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Canceled on row input.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Insert and Copy/Paste

    With pws.Rows(PasteRow)
        .Resize(prCount, cCount).Insert xlShiftDown ' insert i.e. make room
        cvrg.Copy .Cells(1) ' copy/paste
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation

End Sub
```